# How can I integrate wordpress in my website with common authentication?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

A website is developed in core PHP with MySQL database. If we want to integrate Wordpress with that in such a way that we don't have to login in wordpress's wp-login page.
Once we are login in core website, it should automatically login in wordpress.
This mechanism should be applied to admin and front end too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform this programmatically with PHP:

```
require_once( "wordpress/wp-config.php" );
$user = wp_signon( array(
    "user_login" => "username",
    "user_password" => "password",
    "remember" => true
), false );

// see if the call failed
if( get_class( $user ) == "WP_Error" ) {
    die( "oops- wrong user/pass?" );
}
```

It'd be up to you to synchronize or link usernames and passwords with your other system.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I would not need to manage session separately, right?

Comment: This snippet maintains its own session under normal circumstances, but, that design part is completely up to you.

Comment: @pp19dd sorry i know this is an old post, but what if my site uses email and password instead of username and pass? my question on this site is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090396/authentication-integration-with-wordpress